# CORS error with Angular call to Java service

Tags: java, angular, cors

I have an Angular application that makes a call to a Spring Boot Java service in a separate container. This gateway service calls two other services (one Java and one Python) as needed. Everything works fine running four Docker containers locally. When I run this in AWS ECS, I get the following two errors in my browser:

> Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading
> the remote resource at
> http://655b883054184264bf96512da0e137af._http._tcp.gateway-service.local:8084/datasets?page=1&keyword=.
> (Reason: CORS request did not succeed). Status code: (null).
>
> ERROR  Object { headers: {…}, status: 0, statusText: "Unknown Error",
> url:
> "http://655b883054184264bf96512da0e137af._http._tcp.gateway-service.local:8084/datasets?page=1&keyword=",
> ok: false, name: "HttpErrorResponse", message: "Http failure response
> for
> http://655b883054184264bf96512da0e137af._http._tcp.gateway-service.local:8084/datasets?page=1&keyword=:
> 0 Unknown Error", error: error } ​ error: error { target:
> XMLHttpRequest, isTrusted: true, lengthComputable: false, … } ​
> headers: Object { normalizedNames: Map(0), lazyUpdate: null, headers:
> Map(0) } ​ message: "Http failure response for
> http://655b883054184264bf96512da0e137af._http._tcp.gateway-service.local:8084/datasets?page=1&keyword=:
> 0 Unknown Error" ​ name: "HttpErrorResponse" ​ ok: false ​ status: 0 ​
> statusText: "Unknown Error" ​ url:
> "http://655b883054184264bf96512da0e137af._http._tcp.gateway-service.local:8084/datasets?page=1&keyword="

I have a filter in both java services that looks like this:

```java
@Component public class CORSFilter implements Filter {

    public void doFilter(ServletRequest req, ServletResponse res, FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException {
        HttpServletResponse response = (HttpServletResponse) res;
        response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
        response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "POST, GET, PUT, OPTIONS, DELETE, PATCH");
        response.setHeader("Access-Control-Max-Age", "3600");
        response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept");
        chain.doFilter(req, res);
    }

    public void init(FilterConfig filterConfig) {}

    public void destroy() {}
}
```

When running locally, the page loads and I verified that I see the expected CORS header on the gateway service response:

```http
HTTP/1.1 200
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
Access-Control-Allow-Methods: POST, GET, PUT, OPTIONS, DELETE, PATCH
Access-Control-Max-Age: 3600
Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Origin,
X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept
Content-Type: application/json
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Date: Sun, 30 Jan 2022 03:37:36 GMT
Keep-Alive: timeout=60
Connection: keep-alive
```

In case it helps, my Python service also returns a similar CORS header. I'm using the following code to enable CORS in my Python script.

```py
app = Flask(__name__)  CORS(app)
```

Here is one of the Angular calls to the Gateway service:

```js
let resp = this.http.get(API_GATEWAY + "?page=" + page + "&keyword=" + keyword);
```

I tried configuring a proxy in Angular, but that didn't resolve the issue. I also implemented @CrossOrigin("*") by each REST Controller in Java to no avail.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two ways to solve this issue:
first you may need to disable cors and csrf inside the config method of the class that extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter:

```
 @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.cors()
                .and()
                .csrf()
                .disable()
                 .....
```

second you may leave it enabled then:

```
    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http    
                .cors()
                .and()
                .csrf()
                .csrfTokenRepository(CookieCsrfTokenRepository.withHttpOnlyFalse())
                ....
```